# How to play recorded audio file from POVoiceHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im using a control to record voice in an app POVoiceHUD.

https://github.com/polatolu/POVoiceHUD

I seem to missing something getting the file to play/retrieving the recorded audio. The demo project does not include playback of the recorded item that is stored in `[self.voiceHud startForFilePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/MySound.caf", NSHomeDirectory()]];`

Ive tried using:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"playRecording");
// Init audio with playback capability
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
_voiceHud = [[POVoiceHUD alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[_voiceHud play];
}
```

However I get errors `incompatible pointer type`, and `no known class selector`

Comment: hi JSA986 , I have updated my code to play audio sound via POVoiceHUD. Please have a look on my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here POVoiceHUD file is responsible for record your audio file. For playing this recorded file , you will need some line of code inside in your viewVontroller.h & .m as well as POVoiceHUD.h & .m

Try this code

Inside POVoiceHUD.h include this line

```
 AVAudioPlayer *player;

 - (void)playRecording:(NSURL*)_url;
```

POVoiceHUD.m

```
- (void)playRecording:(NSURL*)_url {
    [self cancelRecording];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSError *error;

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_url error:&error];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
```

Inside viewVontroller.h

```
- (IBAction)btnRecordTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnPlayTapped:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)btnRecordTapped:(id)sender {

        [self.voiceHud startForFilePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/MySound.caf", NSHomeDirectory()]];
}

- (IBAction)btnPlayTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.voiceHud cancelRecording];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/MySound.caf", NSHomeDirectory()]];

    [self.voiceHud playRecording:url];
}
```

i hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, that just presents the recording action again `startForFilePath`, im trying to playback the recording

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much for your assistance with this, and your clear description to fix it.  Plus one for you!